# Connecting different batteries in parrallel?

Tags: batteries, charging

I have bought a battery driven load speaker for an upcoming festival. Problem is that the 12V 7Ah battery in the speaker only lasts 12 hours. I need a lot more.

So I've bought a 60Ah car battery in addition. Problem is that the internal battery is soldered inside the speaker, and can't be removed easily. Therefore I consider to just connect the car battery in parrallel when the internal battery is done.

In this case I will have the internal battery at ~10.5V in parrallel with the fresh car battery at ~12.8V.

The internal battery is this: http://www.yuasabatteries.com/pdfs/NP_7_12_DataSheet.pdf and it looks like the charging voltage is ~13.8V, but what happens then when I connect the car battery? and will this work without distroying the internal battery and the speaker completly? (I can live with it being a worn a little)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work with no problems for occasional use, although it is not recommended to mix battery sizes or types when making a large battery bannk for permanent use.

Comment: The fresh car battery will charge the internal battery to the same voltage pretty promptly (limited by connection resistance) and then they will discharge together.  While it is not considered ideal use it would work ok. Allowing the internal battery to discharge excessively would do it much more damage.  Connecting the external battery from the start when both are fully charged would be the kindest and most energy efficient option.